# how to place the soap url values in textviews in android

Tags: android, split, substring

How to place the soap url values in textviews in android,I want to show the datas in particular order,i split the data's one by one but now i want to place the data's in particular textview,Edittext ,how can i do that could u please help...Thanks in advance

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Sessionamount";

        private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "Sessionamount";

        private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

       private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "220.226.170.5/service.asmx?WSDL";

        TextView tvData1,ts;
        EditText edata;
        ImageView button;
        String Date;
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport;
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
        Object response;
        //SoapPrimitive s;
        ProgressDialog progress;
   // 
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            tvData1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            ts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            edata = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);



        // calendar function    


            final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                        int dayOfMonth) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    updateLabel();
                }

                private void updateLabel() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
                    edata.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));


                }

            };

    // listener for button

           edata.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);*/

                    envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet=true;
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                    httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

                    try {

                         serviceCall();

                    } catch (Exception exception) {

                        tvData1.setText(exception.toString()
                            + " Or No Records Found!");

                    }

                }
            });

                }


        void serviceCall() {

            progress.setMessage("Loading Contents");
            progress.show();

            progress.setMessage("Redirecting credientials");
            progress.show();

                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {

                        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                        response = envelope.getResponse();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), 1)
                                .show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), 1)
                                .show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                }


                @Override

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            String str = "";

            if (progress != null)
                progress.dismiss();
            if (response !=null)
            {
        /* private static List <String> parse (String str)
                {
                    String temp; 
                List <String> list = new ArrayList <String> (); 
                if (str!= null    && Str.length ()> 0) 
                {
                int start = str.indexOf ("string"); 
                int end = str.lastIndexOf (";"); 
                temp = str.substring (start, end - 3); 
                String [] test = temp.split (";"); 
                for (int i = 0; i <test.length; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0) {temp = test [i]. substring (7);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                    temp = test [i]. substring (8);
                    } 
                    int index = temp.indexOf (","); 
                    list.add (temp.substring (0, index));
                    }}
                return list;
                } */
                String resultArr[] = response.toString().split(";");

                /*for(int i=0;i<resultArr.length;i++)
                {
                    str=str+resultArr[i]+"\n\n";
                    tvData1.setText(str);

                }*/

                for(int i=0;i<resultArr.length;i++)
                {
                    str=str+resultArr[i]+"\n\n";
                    //tvData1.setText(str);
                    edata.setText(str);
                    tvData1.setText(str);
            }

            } else
                //tvData1.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Records Found", 1)
                        .show();
            }   

    }.execute();


        }   
    }




    //this is my xml

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/splash"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="DD/MM/YY"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/search" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

             android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="@drawable/roundborder"
                android:text="Session                         Amount"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

        <!--     <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Amount"
                  android:background="@drawable/roundborder"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" /> -->

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"



            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"



      android:background="@drawable/roundborder"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>



//this is the format i need
​session                     Amount
Afternoon                   68788798
Morning                       87686978
Evening                       24232

I want to get the total amount of those amounts,I just add(+)  amount alone
How can i add​
Is there any concept

//The URL look like this,

​Afternoon-99127.79;Night-67236.27;Morning-61876.65;Evening-20271.42;Housekeeping-5444.05;
```

Comment: put directly...by your textview.settext method...whats the problem..

Comment: Post the contents and length of `resultArr`

Comment: the conents are in the last line of my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do like below

```
          for(int i=0;i<resultArr.length;i++)
          {
                str=str+resultArr[i]+"\n\n";
                //tvData1.setText(str);
                edata.setText(str);
                tvData1.setText(str);
           }
```

then edittext and textviews have same value.

So what you should do is,

```
                tvData1.setText(resultArr[0]);
                edata.setText(resultArr[1]);      // this is the general idea. You can do this only if you know the exact position of the value and length of the array.
                tvData1.setText(resultArr[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!I had a another doubt how to split a string,For example in my link i want to split in between the "-",Is there any possiblities

Comment: If my above answer helped you then please upvote and tick mark it first. It will be helpful for others. If you have any other questions then please ask it in different thread and send me the link. Happy to help you.

Comment: If you want to split at "-" then `String[] array = str.split("-");`

Comment: @ Aniruddha this is my new thread...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502553/how-to-split-the-datas-in-android-while-using-soap

Comment: @user3736314 I have answered to that question, please accept it (tick mark)