# How to split the datas in android while using soap

Tags: android, string, split, substring

I had a doubt while using soap ,how to split a string,Is there any possibility.

```
//this the original data

Afternoon-99127.79;
Night-67236.27;
Morning-61876.65;
Evening-20271.42;
Housekeeping-5444.05;

I need;
Afternoon        99127.79
Night            67236
Morning          61876.65;
Evening          20271.42;
Housekeeping     5444.05;
```

I split using semicolon and then i don't know how to use the sub strings,Use of start and end index i don't know how to give the values..Actually i want to  split before "-" and after "-".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String total_string = "Afternoon-99127.79;Night-67236.27;Morning-61876.65;Evening-20271.42;Housekeeping-5444.05;";

String[] spilted_string = total_string.split(";");
for (int i=0;i<spilted_string.length;i++){
   System.out.println(spilted_string[i].split("-")[0]);
   System.out.println(spilted_string[i].split("-")[1]);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/1DCJEL)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
String soapString = "Afternoon-99127.79;" +"Night-67236.27;" +"Morning-61876.65;" +"Evening-20271.42;" +"Housekeeping-5444.05;";

String[] splitedArray = soapString.split(";");
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 for (int i=0;i<splitedArray.length;i++){
   HashMap<String,String> row =new HashMap<String, String>();
   row.put("firstString",splitedArray[i].split("-")[0]);
   row.put("secondString",splitedArray[i].split("-")[1]);
   list.add(row);
 }

 for (HashMap<String,String> data : list){
       System.out.println(data.get("firstString") +" "+data.get("secondString"));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Split by `;` which'll give you an array of elements separated by `-`. Then split each array item by `-`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SplitEx {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String data = "Afternoon-99127.79;Night-67236.27;Morning-61876.65;Evening-20271.42;Housekeeping-5444.05;";

        String[] a = data.split(";");
        String[] b = new String[a.length];

        for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
             b[i] = a[i].replace("-"," ");
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < b.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(" " +b[i]);

        }


    }

}
```

**OUTPUT OF ARRAY B**

```
Afternoon 99127.79
Night 67236.27
Morning 61876.65
Evening 20271.42
Housekeeping 5444.05
```

Answer (score 0):

use Strin[] a = myString..split("-");
This code piece will split the String by "-" and store it in string array.

But I recommend you to use Sparse array. Transfer your data using SparseArray and accept it in the same way. It is faster than Hashmap. Try it.